# How to run Espresso instrumentation tests in parallel in Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

Currently I run Espresso tests on Firebase / Google Test Lab, but it takes time to run them all, as they run in sequentially.

Is there a way to run them in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to shard your tests so that you can kick off multiple batches of test that can run in parallel on different devices.  Firebase doesn't provide a way to do this directly, but there is an open source project called [Flank](https://github.com/TestArmada/flank) that can help.